# WindowsIdentity.Impersonate throws ''Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))' after April 2018 (1803) update

Tags: windows-10, impersonation, .net-4.6

Our installer app uses the following code to verify service account permissions:

```
try
{
    using (svcIdentity.Impersonate())
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))  // <<<
        {
            conn.Open();
            ...
```

Omitted for brevity:

- The `svcIdentity` WindowsIdentity is obtained by using the Win32 LSA `LogonUser` function in advapi32.dll and `LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE`.
- `builder` is a SqlConnectionStringBuilder that builds a connectionstring to a local SQL Server database.

Targeting .Net Framework 4.6.

The app runs elevated (`requestedExecutionLevel level='requireAdministrator'` in the app.manifest).

This code ran flawless until Windows 10 version 1803 (April 2018 update). Since then, the SqlConnection constructor (marked <<<) throws an exception:

```
The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.
```

The inner exception provides more insight:

```
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

Stack trace:

```
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)
   at System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.RawEvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.EvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath)
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord record)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()
```

The stack trace indicates the SqlConnection constructor fails to open a configuration section. Our `app.config` does not have a connectionstrings section and `machine.config` and `security.config` on the tested computers haven't changed since 2017.

The code works when:

- Commenting out `using (svcIdentity.Impersonate)`,

  or
- when setting a breakpoint on the line immediately above the SqlConnection constructor (`{`) and stepping through the code (???),

  or
- when adding our application to the registry key mentioned at the end of [KB945701](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/945701)

That KB article about a fix for Internet Explorer 9 seems unrelated, except that `GetLocationEvidence` on the first line of the stack trace seems to take a `SecurityZone` into account, which applications listed in the corresponding registry key seem to ignore.

Now my question:

Can anybody help me understand what exactly is going wrong, and if there is a better way to fix this than with an obscure registry key? It seems a 'coincidence' that this registry change works and I'm afraid our code might break again if we don't understand exactly why it fails.

Thx.

Comment: At run time, the CLR gathers evidence on an assembly, which it uses to make security decisions as the code is executed. Though I can't be 100% without looking through Windows assemblies, it seems like your fix works because it exempts your site from the Code Access Security policies on your computer. The others work because they generate different evidence than your release version. The applied Windows update probably made changes to the underlying functions and returned a different result that killed your app.

Comment: Thanks for including the registry key fix. That's at least a little workaround that worked for me.